# Apollo GraphQL - watchQuery and networkErrors issue

Tags: javascript, angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

**TL;DR;**

When the graphQL server is not available, watchQuery loading flag never changes to false, thus the error handling should be done with apollo-link-error.

Is there any way to fix the issue with watchQuery?

---

I've developed a small Angular GraphQL app. One of the features is triggering a simple query like this one:

```
  this.apollo
    .watchQuery<any>({
      query: this.BookingByID,
      variables: {
        bookingCode: id
      }
    })
    .valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
      this.booking = result.data.booking;
      this.loading = result.loading;
      this.error = result.errors;
    });
```

I wanted to test the app behavior when the network or the Graphql server are failing. These are the scenarios that I tried.

- No Internet Connection
- GraphQL Server unreachable.

**No Internet Connection**

Without internet connection `this.error` works fine. I'm able to detect the error and to display the proper message.

**GraphQL Server unreachable**

When the GraphQL server is not available I'm experiencing an issue. The query loading status remains "true" even when I get a network error. (Apollo Error. Code 0. Unknown error).

After doing some research I read that **apollo-link-error module** allows you to handle the networkErrors in a better way. So I've implemented something like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';

const uri = 'http://localhost:4000'; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here

export function createApollo( httpLink: HttpLink ) {
  const http = httpLink.create({uri});
  const error = onError(({networkError}) => {
    console.log(networkError);
  });

  return {
    link: error.concat(http),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      }
    }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

After implementing apollo-link-error, I'm able to see the error in the browser console. But I'm still wondering why does watchQuery loading status indicator not change from loading=true to loading=false.

**template.html**

```
<p *ngIf="loading">Loading...</p>
<p *ngIf="error">{{ error | json }}</p>
```

If the solution is to move on with the apollo-link-error approach, what is the proper way of doing it? How should I notify the view about the error? Parameter? Route? Is there any best practice? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance,

Guillermo